# Navigation bar reconfigures links from sections of SharePoint pages, removing everything after '#'

Tags: navigation, url, hyperlink, sub-site, top-link-bar

I am currently configuring my navigation bar in SharePoint online (Office365 application). My SharePoint site exists of two pages:

- Home page
- Info page

  - [section 1] Who are we?
  - [section 2] What do we do?
  - [section 3] Our employees

As you can see, the Info page contains three sections, where I can link to each section as follows:

- https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/ScienceDepartment/SitePages/Info.aspx#who-are-we
- https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/ScienceDepartment/SitePages/Info.aspx#what-do-we-do
- https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/ScienceDepartment/SitePages/Info.aspx#our-employees

Now my navigation bar has the same structure as the bullet points above: two main labels linking to 'Home' and 'Info' respectively, where 'Info' also has the three sublabels.

I would like each sublabel in the navigation bar to link to the related section on the Info page. However when I add the link to the label, SharePoint automatically reconfigures the URL by removing everything after the `#` in the URL, hence only linking to the 'Info' page in general (https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/ScienceDepartment/SitePages/Info.aspx).

How can I change this behaviour in the settings of SharePoint? Or is this known as a sort of bug (or shortcoming) of SharePoint sites?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a **workaround**:

If you add an empty source parameter to the URL it does work, place `?source=` inbetween the `.aspx` and the hashtag part `#` of the URL.
So instead of

https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/ScienceDepartment/SitePages/Info.aspx#who-are-we

you will get

https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/ScienceDepartment/SitePages/Info.aspx?source=#who-are-we